Delphi EncodeDateTime and EncodeTime Time portions are different
Here is an example which demonstrates the problem:
var
   fdt, fndt : Double;
   dt, dt2 : TDateTime;
begin
    dt := EncodeDateTime(2023, 12, 31, //
        20, 10, 5, 100);
    dt2 := EncodeTime(20, 10, 5, 100);
    fdt := Frac(dt);
    fndt := Frac(dt2);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Equal: ' + BoolToStr(fdt = fndt, True) + CRLF + //
        FloatToStr(fdt) + CRLF +  //
        FloatToStr(fndt) + CRLF +  //
        FormatDateTime('HH:NN:SS ZZZ', fdt) + CRLF +  //
        FormatDateTime('HH:NN:SS ZZZ', fndt) + CRLF +  //
        ''
        );
    Exit;

The result is:
 Equal: False 
 0,840336805558763 
 0,840336805555556 
 20:10:05 100
 20:10:05 100

So as you see the Time portion is not the same as Double, but same as Formatted String.
Why they are different?
As I know that EncodeDateTime does EncodeDate + EncodeTime.
And the Date = Trunc(Date).
So the fractional part has to be same! But it isn't. Why?
Maybe some time zone info?
Thank you for any info about it.
Env: Win 11, Delphi S10, 32bit Exe. Time zone: Europe/Budapest (+2/+1).

In Delphi, as you know, datetime values are floats (doubles), and this is how doubles work. There are tens of thousands of Qs on this topic on the WWW. Here's one of them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Are you unconsciously assuming that because the date is a whole number and the time is a fraction, that a TDateTime holds both an integer part and a fractional part?

Because that's how it works. If we need just the Date part, we have to use Trunc(DT), if we need to use the Time part, we have to use Frac(DT).
From the help:
"The integral part of a TDateTime value is the number of days that have passed since December 30, 1899. The fractional part of a TDateTime value is the time of day."
I understand that floats are not hold correct values. But Doubles are mostly correct in these ranges. So it's a little bit strange.

So it seems to be now I can compare two time parts if I will recode them (Decode + Encode), and I will compare these recoded values.

Don't compare datetime with =. Do it with TMath.SameValue(). They are doubles...

Comparing floating point values for equality using the = operator is generally not accurate due to the inaccurate nature of floating point types. Just because the inputs are identical does not guarantee the floats are identical.
You have to take an epsilon into account to see if floating point values are "close enough" to be considered equal.  You can use Math.SameValue() for that purpose.
However, in this case, you can use DateUtils.SameTime() or DateUtils.CompareTime() instead. The SameTime() documentation even states the following:

Note: It is possible to create two TDateTime values whose time portions differ numerically when viewed as floating point types, but which represent the same hour, minute, second, and millisecond. SameTime allows applications to determine when two TDateTime values represent the same time, even when the fractional parts of the values differ.

